# Node.js: Threaded Workers with Promises and a Manager of Async Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, es6-promise

I'm currently trying to make a simple program that has a Manager and some workers. The manager checks what the value the workers have computed. I'm starting to understand and kinda push the limits of what Async functions. I'm not sure if it is a issue with my logic or if it is an issue with the implementation.

The Code is primary built with two classes, Manager and Worker. The goal of the manager is to manage an array of workers. Also, when the worker has completed it will just print out that it has completed its work or there is a 50/50 chance the worker will spawn a new worker.

The worker has a flag stating if it is working or if it is open to be re-run. The default `cool_function` that the worker runs is simply `1 + 1`.

```
class Worker {
  constructor(cool_function) {
    this.cool_function = cool_function;
  }

  async run() {
    return this.cool_function();
  }

  getWorking() {
    return this.working;
  }
}

class Manager {
  constructor() {
    this.workers = [];
  }

  addWorker(cool_function = (async() => {return 1 + 1})) {
    this.workers.push(new Worker(cool_function));
  }

  async run() {
    while(true) {
      for(var i = 0; i < this.workers.length; i++) {
        let work = this.workers[i].run();
        work.then((function(value) {
          console.log("Worker #" + i + " did the work and got: " + value + "!");
          if(Math.random() > .5) {
            console.log("Worker #" + i + " just spawned a new worker(Worker #" + (this.workers.length + 1) + ")");
            this.workers.push(new Worker());
          }
        }).bind(this));
      }
    }
  }
}

async function runManager() {
  let manager = new Manager();
  manager.addWorker();
  manager.run();
}

runManager();
```

What ends up happening is that the while loop never terminates, like it is suppose to, however, none of my `console.log()` are being executed too... Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I don't see any awaits in your code. Go back to the drawing board. You don't have a grasp on what async/await is.

Comment: @Darkrum I don't need awaits to do async functions... The point is to do a series of work and spawn off workers to do tasks while the manager checks back every cycle. I don't want the Manager or Workers waiting on the main thread.

Comment: async doesn't do anything without await. Also while loops don't work without await if the code block it is executing is async/next clock tick.

Comment: Your workers can use await why would the main thread have any influence on them

Comment: Your question title mentions "Threaded Workers", but nothing in your code is threaded? Promises or async/await have nothing to do with multi-threading. They're just an abstraction over asynchronous results. You have an infinite loop in your code (`while (true) for (var i=0; i<0; ) {}`), so no asynchronous callback will ever take place.